# MVVM in Visual Studio - how do I read from my Microsoft SQL tables into a c# viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I've created a Microsoft SQL Server table. I've imported this as a data model to a visual studio WPF project. It's created this model for me:

```
namespace MyProj.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Element
    {
        public int Pk { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I've also created a ViewModel with IPropertyChanged etc. but let's ignore the data-binding bits:

```
namespace MyProj.ViewModels
{
    public class ElementVM
    {
        public ElementVM()
        {
            Elements = GetElementList();
        }

        ObservableCollection<Element> GetElementList()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Element> elements = new ObservableCollection<Element>();
            // I'd like to be querying my database here
            return elements;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Element> _elements;
        public ObservableCollection<Element> Elements
        {
            get { return _elements; }
            set
            {
                _elements = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So - my question is about getting my element list
1) How do I query the database from here? I have the model but when I'm trying to write "Linq to SQL" queries like

```
elements = 
    from element in Models.Element
    where 'I just don't know what to put here
```

I'm not getting good intellisense. I think it's just referring to empty models instead of datasets

2) Am I using the correct object here? (An observable collection - I feel like I could be using DataTables here!! what is the best option?)

Comment: Sounds like your question is perhaps _"how to I read data from a database?"_.  If so that has nothing to do with MVVM.  MVVM does not define _how_ the models are _populated_.  In saying that, you might want to look at _service injection_ - a popular pattern for delegating work to other parts of the system instead of getting the VM to do it.

Comment: 2) Yes you should be using `ObservableCollection<>` because it tells WPF more than what a `DataTable` will

Comment: OK, so, I took away the MVVM tag. From a MySQL table I'd just run a query. The bit I'm confused about is the VM within Microsoft context - even if I can just run a query "Select * from Element" how does this translate to the viewmodel?

Comment: @jamheadart: Database is your M, not VM. You don't want to read the database directly into VM because, e. g., the VM runs in the UI thread whereas accessing the DB is definitely slow and must be done in a background task. (But anyway from design perspective the DB is model.)

Comment: So WHERE do I read the database into and how do I translate that to a viewmodel? In the examples I see they create mock db's inside a viewmodel to show how that binds to the UI, so I've been trying to go from there.